# Post HTTP array angular 7 and .NET core web api

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have written Http postcode from angular 7 to asp.net core web API. 
I am attaching code snippets below. I am getting an empty array in .net core API.
here is my code in Angular 7 written in Component.ts file

```
saveEducation(edu: Education[]) { const obj = new Education(this._http, 
this._deoServices);
obj.saveEducation(edu).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe((res) => 
{
 // this.eduData = res;
 });
}
```

Here is the Code written in Component model class

```
saveEducation(edu: Education[])  {
return this._service.saveEducation('/api/Deo/SaveEducation', edu);
}
```

And here is the code is written in the `service.ts` file.

```
public saveEducation(api: string , model: Education[]): Observable<boolean> 
{
     return this._http.post<boolean>(api, {education: model.values}, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
         'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
       })
    });
}
```

And here is The Web API code accepting an array.

```
public bool SaveEducation( dynamic[] edu)
{
     var obj = new Candidate_Educational_Info_Table(_context);
    return obj.SaveEducation(edu);
}
```

Kindly help me in finding error as I am getting array empty

[Here is network tab results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Da32C.png)

[Network tab second ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq8Ij.png)

[Here is the image where i am getting null array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da8Uo.png)

[Here is Request Header screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg9SU.png)

Comment: returning a boolean is not JSON

Comment: What should I return then? I am returning true or false if data is posted successfully

Comment: Why are you returning true or false? What is your goal?

Comment: Not such goal. I can remove boolean but what return type then I should used?

Comment: I am having problem that whether error is in my angular code or is in web api code as I am getting empty array in web api when I debug and post data from angular

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{education: model.values}` with just  `model.values`.

It will look like this now,

```
this._http.post<boolean>(api, model.values, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
    })
});
```

Because, by default, WebAPI is configured to read from the body. Optionally, you can add `FromBody` in WebAPI.

```
public IActionResult SaveEducation([FromBody]Education[] edu)
{
     var obj = new Candidate_Educational_Info_Table(_context);
     var result = obj.SaveEducation(edu);
     return Ok(new { sucess = result });
}
```

Comment: this doesn't work when I used [FromBody] I get following error|
POST http://localhost:50915/api/Deo/SaveEducation 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Did you also replace {education: model.values} with model.values as per my comment above.

Comment: Ok I am waiting as I am facing this problem from 2 days but not getting a solution

Comment: I did two changes above. Try those also. First, use Education type DTO instead of dynamic. Second, return some C# object that can be serializable into JSON. Not put a breakpoint over API method and see what you get. Also keep Chrome's Network tab open before making the request to check the request/response headers & post data.

Comment: It is giving error of bad request 400 when I remove [FromBody ]it runs smoothly

Comment: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

Comment: if network tab shows success then what is the problem?

Comment: can you please attach screenshot with requet payload in the network tab

Comment: I have attached screen shots in the question above

Comment: I can't see the screenshot of Request Header..please attach that one also so that I can see what data is being posted?

Comment: I attached that one

Comment: that's the problem. I can see that there no data being posted by the browser.

Comment: So the issue is that your angular app is not posting data properly.

Comment: Yes I am getting data till Post method but that method is not posting

Comment: Could you please update the code of saveEducation method in above question? Also I would recommend to put a debugger before http.post & analyze the array value which you want to post.

Comment: I have solved this. There was error in references I have created a wrong constructor